# É possível utilizar o atributo autocomplete em "textarea/select"?

Tags: html5

Sei que o atributo pode ser utilizado no elemento `input`

```
<input type="text" name="email" autocomplete="on" />
```

Segundo a [*MDN Web Docs*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea), o elemento `textarea` inclui os atributos globais a qual consta o `autocomplete` mas ao testar na versão *59.0.3 (64-bit)* do *Firefox*, simplesmente não funcionou:

```
<textarea name="mensagem" autocomplete="on"></textarea>
```

Veja que na sessão *Compatibilidade do Navegador* consta que funciona no *Firefox* a partir da versão *59*, e pesquisando no *Google* encontrei lugares falando que funciona no *Chrome* a partir da versão *66*, mas testei na versão *66.0.3359.139 (Versão oficial) 64 bits* e também não funcionou.

Já na comunidade *WHATWG*, consta que o atributo pode ser atribuído tanto em elementos [`textarea`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-textarea-element) como nos elementos [`select`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-select-element), mas ambos não funcionam.

```
<select name="cor" autocomplete="on">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Azul">Azul</option>
  <option value="Preto">Preto</option>
  <option value="Verde">Verde</option>
</select>
```

A pergunta: Estou fazendo o uso corretamente ?

#### Referências

- [MDN Web Docs - textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)
- [WHATWG - textarea](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-textarea-element)
- [WHATWG - select](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-select-element)

Comment: Estou no celular e não consigo pesquisar direito, mas parece que a [interface do elemento](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement) define o *autocomplete* como experimental, então talvez precise habilitar o suporte nas configurações do navegador.

Comment: No select como ficaria o autocomplete? Vc quer que o usuário digite e já apareça as opções do combo fazendo um tipo de filtro. Tipo começa a digitar a letra "A" e aparece no combo a cor "Azul" por exemplo?

Comment: Na documentação está escrito: "`on`: O browser pode completar automaticamente o valor baseado nos valores que o usuário entrou **em sessões anteriores**". É esse o comportamento que você está testando?

Comment: @hugocsl esse autocomplete será igual ao do `input` creio eu, creio que será o padrão do navegador, mas como dito na pergunta, a documentação diz que o atributo pode ser utilizado nos dois elementos, mas não funciona em nenhum deles.

Comment: Cara eu não entendi direito rss, mas parece que vc quer um `<datalist>` e não um `<select>`...

Comment: http://www.endreywalder.com/blog/html5-autocomplete-with-optional-select/

Comment: @hugocsl não, não é `datalist` veja os links de referência que citei, veja que consta o atributo `autocomplete`

Comment: Existe um jeito de fazer isso através de uma biblioteca do Jquery. http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ Segue abaixo link desse exemplo funcionando. http://output.jsbin.com/cezemetida/1 Aqui o link da resposta a essa pergunta no StackOverflow em inglês. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518442/autocomplete-functionality-on-a-textarea Um abraço !

Answer (score 10):

O `autocomplete` nos elementos `textarea` e `select` possui um comportamento diferente em relação aos elementos `input`.

Enquanto que nos `input`s o `autocomplete` (quando setado `on`) é ativado quando você começa a digitar e o navegador mostra valores já digitados (guardados no cache) que coincidem com o que você está digitando naquele momento, no `textarea` e `select` ele funciona apenas quando a página sofre um *reload* com cache, ou seja teclando <kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> ou clicando no botão  do navegador, mantendo:

- No `textarea`: o texto que foi digitado antes do refresh.
- No `select`: a `option` selecionada antes do refresh.

Resumindo, a função do `autocomplete` nesses elementos (`textarea` e `select`) nada mais é do que **manter os valores** (`on`) ou **não manter** (`off`) ao fazer um *reload* simples como mencionado anteriormente.

**Mas há de se notar** que caso não haja o atributo `autocomplete` no elemento, o navegador irá manter os valores mesmo assim, como se tivesse um `autocomplete="on"`. Logo, o `autocomplete` se torna útil apenas com o valor `off`, quando você não quer de forma alguma que os valores permaneçam nos elementos mesmo após um *reload* simples.

> Lembrando que esta abordagem se refere exclusivamente ao Firefox na
>   versão igual ou superior à apontada na pergunta (estou usando Firefox versão 60.0.1 64-bits) e também conforme informado na tabela de compatibilidade da **[documentação no MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)**.

### Edit

Não imagine que o `autocomplete="on"` no `textarea` ou `select` fará aparecer sugestões como aparece nos campos `input`. Isso ainda não existe (e acho até bom :D).

Comment: Certo, não sabia dessa, mas e quanto ao *Chrome* ?

Comment: Pela tabela de compatibilidade, o Chrome não tem suporte. Onde vc viu que ele suporta? Pelos teste que realizei aqui, o `autocomplete` não tem qualquer efeito no Chrome no textarea e select.

Comment: No *MDN* a documentação do `select` não consta o `autocomplete` já na [WHATWG - select](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-select-element) consta.

Comment: Se você der uma olhada na tabela no [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-autocomplete-onoff) verá que há muitas "ressalvas" para o uso do autocomplete em diferentes navegadores.